# Occasional "fatal: not a git repository" in a git worktree

Tags: git, git-worktree

I have 4 Ubuntu machines and a Jenkins job runs on them. A shared disk is mounted to them as `/data/repositories/`. Under it, there are many non-bare repositories created by `git clone <url> --no-checkout -b master`.

When the job is triggered, it runs these step:

1. In `/data/repositories/foo`, fetch `Branch A` and `Branch B`
2. Parse `Branch B` head and get its commit `SHA1VALUE`
3. Create a work tree by `git worktree add --no-checkout /path/to/worktree SHA1VALUE`
4. Get the changed files in `Branch A` head
5. Enable sparse checkout in `/path/to/worktree`
6. Write the changed files into `/data/repositories/foo/.git/worktrees/xx/info/sparse-checkout`
7. Run `git checkout` in `/path/to/worktree` to check out these files
8. Use `git cherry-pick` to apply `Branch A` head onto `SHA1VALUE` in `/path/to/worktree`
9. Push the new commit to `Branch B`.

`/path/to/worktree` is not on the shared disk but on each machine's own disk. In Step 7 and Step 9, it may occasionally raise an error `fatal: not a git repository /data/repositories/foo/.git/worktrees/xx`. When the error occurs, `/data/repositories/foo/.git/worktrees/xx` is not there as if it's been deleted by some process or thread right before the step. In the job, it won't be deleted on purpose until the job is finished or an exception is raised in these steps.

If I rebuild the job with the same parameters, the problem does not occur again.

If `/data/repositories/foo/.git/worktrees/xx` is not successfully created in the first place, it would be detected during these steps and Step 8 would always fail.

Multiple jobs could run on the same `/data/repositories/foo` at the same time. But in `/data/repositories/foo/.git/worktrees/xx/info/sparse-checkout`, the `xx` part is unique.

Thanks for any clues.

Comment: I have seen it in relation with this new checks for permissions (`--add safe.directory`). Is there a chance it could be related in your environment?

Comment: @eftshift0 Thanks. In my case the owner of the shared repository is the same with the user that runs the jobs on the machines. But I don't know if the users with the same name from different machines can be considered as the same owner. Besides, if the problem is related with `safe.directory`, I think all jobs should fail. Anyway, I'll have a try.

Comment: I'd bet you're hitting some race condition where the locking that Git uses (which depends on POSIX semantics) isn't supported by whatever mount point / file system type you're using, so that `git worktree add` doesn't complete correctly. (Are you using NFS, SMB, or ....?)

Comment: @torek Thanks for the clues. I agree with you. The race condition is the most possible suspect. The registered worktree entry in the main repository gets deleted due to some race condition, and the root cause could be the file system type. I know little about file system types. I'll consult our server experts.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @torek. Although it's still not clear how exactly the problem is caused, I found a solution to fix it. According to the solution, the root cause is high likely related with race condition and file system types as @torek pointed out.

The shared disk is NFS and the non-shared is EXT4. So, the main repository resides in NFS system and its worktrees are created in EXT4 system. Under some unknown condition with concurrent jobs running, the worktree gitdir in the main repository gets deleted unexpectedly, and of course the worktree is disabled.

The solution is to create the worktrees in the shared disk, so that the main repository and worktrees are on the same disk. After testing for about 8 hours, the problem does not occur again.